# While installing Sitecore commerce 9 update 3 getting IIS location not found

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework, iis

Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Cannot find path 'IIS:\Sites\xxxx.mysite.name' because it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was missing was the Sitecore XP website was with different name hence was unable to figure-out the location where sitecore commerce needs to be installed.

I did install sitecore XP 9.0.2 version with same site name and run this SIF again and it work well.